Read the content of a Sharepoint file using the API
I want to build an integration with SharePoint platform and use the API provided.
The goal is to fetch the content of every document in a site.
I created an app in order to use it for OAuth2.
The application has the following permissions:

AllSites.Read

AllSites.Write


Steps I did so far:
I am trying to fetch all sites using the following URL
Url: https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites?search=%5C\*
After I fetch the site id I wanted to fetch the drives so I used
Url: https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/xxxxx.sharepoint.com/drives/
And then I use the drive id to fetch all the items in the drive:
- Url: https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/xxxxx.sharepoint.com/drives/%7Bdrive-id%7D/items/root/children
- But this endpoint provides a url that downloads the file I only need to read the content.
I also did this:
During the implementation I also tried to fetch the content of each document in the list of the xxxxx.sharepoint.com site.(list id and item id in the following URL are valid)
- Url https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/xxxxx.sharepoint.com/lists/%7Blist-id%7D/items/%7Bitem-id%7D/driveItem/content
The above returns a binary response and I cannot read the actual content of the document.
I tried to decode the content using iso-8859-1 and utf-8, but I did not manage to read the content of the file.
Is there any endpoint I can use in order to read the content of a file?
I also opened an discussion on Microsoft portal.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1651755/read-the-content-of-a-sharepoint-file-using-the-ap?comment=question
